# What is the most general trait I can use to allow for accessing the middle element of a collection?

Tags: rust, traits

I have a helper function that finds the middle element in a vector:

```
fn get_middle<T>(elements: Vec<T>) -> T {
    elements[elements.len() / 2]
}
```

This allows us to use our helper like so:

```
get_middle(vec![1, 2, 3])
```

There are other structs which are also indexable and have a length. We've really narrowed the usefulness of this helper by only working with `Vec<T>`. For example, `Range`s can't be passed in. Nor can custom datatypes that behave like a vector.

What is the most general trait I can use to constrain `elements` such that it allows for things like:

```
get_middle(vec![1, 2, 3])
// as well as...
get_middle(0..3)
```

I recall reading that ranges can be cast to slices, but that doesn't seem to be the case. Changing the type to `&[T]` gives an error, and attempting to follow its suggestion by casting with `<&[T]>::from(0..3)` doesn't seem to work. Looking at the docs for `Range` and `Vec`, it seems like the `Index` trait is half of what I want, but there doesn't seem to be a trait for `len()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want [`ExactSizeIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.ExactSizeIterator.html) with `IntoIterator`:

```
fn get_middle<T, U>(elements: U) -> Option<T>
where
    U: IntoIterator<Item = T>,
    U::IntoIter: ExactSizeIterator,
{
    let mut it = elements.into_iter();
    let len = it.len();

    it.nth(len / 2)
}

fn main() {
    assert_eq!(get_middle(vec![1, 2, 3]), Some(2));
    assert_eq!(get_middle(0..3), Some(1));
}
```

Note that the `nth` is implemented as a random access if the source of the iterator supports it (for example, a slice or a range).

Comment: Does this still give random access though? Wouldn't I need to `elements.into_iter().collect()` to get random access (which at that point I also have the length)?

Comment: That'll do it. Thanks!